# Group by, Complex query

Tags: soql, group-by

I am trying to do a query that engloves two different querys, the idea is spend just one soql query instead two but I don´t find the way.

```
        AggregateResult[] results = [
                SELECT city__c,
                        min(Start_time__c) startTime,
                        max(End_Time__c) endTime
                FROM Event
                WHERE field2__c = :value1
                AND Start_Time_UTC__c > :previousTime
                AND End_Time_UTC__c < :nextTime
                GROUP BY city__c,
                        field2__c
                ORDER BY min(Start_Time__c)
        ];

        List<GroupedEvents> gEvents = new List<GroupedEvents>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            AggregateResult result = results[i];

            gEvents.add(new GroupedEvents(result));
        }
```

This is the query, I call it twice one for previous events and another for future events.
I merge those events as a single one if they happen in the same city, this way I just have a big event per city before and the same after.

Real events_______: AAAABBAAACC [City change] CCABBBBAACC

What I want to see: A---B-A--C- [City change] C-AB---A-C-

The idea is merge both querys in one.

```
  Map<String, List<GroupedEvents>> groupedEventsMap = new Map<String, List<GroupedEvents>>();
  groupedEventsMap.put( 'previousEvents', new List<GroupedEvents>());
  groupedOEventsMap.put( 'nextEvents', new List<GroupedEvents>());

  AggregateResult[] results = [
        SELECT city__c,
        min(Start_time__c) startTime,
        max(End_Time__c) endTime
            FROM Event
            WHERE field2__c = :value1
                AND (
                        (Start_Time__c > :previousLeaveTime
                         AND End_Time__c < :currentArriveTime)

                    OR  (Start_Time__c > :currentLeaveTime
                         AND End_Time__c < :nextLeaveTime)
                )

                GROUP BY city__c,
                    field2__c
                ORDER BY min(Start_Time__c)
   ];


   for (Integer i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        AggregateResult result = results[i];

        GroupedEvents gEvents = new GroupedEvents(result);

        if(groupedEvents.Start_Time__c <= currentArriveTime){
            groupedEventsMap.get('previousEvents').add(gEvents);
        } else {
            groupedEventsMap.get('nextevents').add(gEvents);
        }
    }
```

> The problem comes when you have events in the same city just before
>   and after, in this case they are merged as one that overlaps the city
>   time.

Real events___________________: AAAABBAAACC [City change] CCABBBBAACC

What I want to see____________: A---B-A--C- [City change] C-AB---A-C-

What I see with a single query: A---B-A--C- [City change] --AB---A-C-

See the C after city change is missing since it is considered a single event starting in the first city and ending in the second one.

Something like adding a constraint in the group by would help, but it is not possible

```
GROUP BY city__c,
    field2__c,
    End_Time__c < :currentLeaveTime
```

Do you know if there is a way to do it?